# Ignore case-sensitive input in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array, case-sensitive

I want to search a value in an array, but the search should ignore lower/upper-case letters.
How can I accomplish this?

This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "ajax.php",
dataType: "json",
data: { pageType: pageType, input: request.term, dataString: 'getPageInfo' },
success: function(data) 
{                                               
var values = $.map(data, function(item) { return {id: item.id, label: item.label, value: item.value}; });   
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i].label.split(',').indexOf(request.term) >= 0) {
       var found = values[i];
    }
}       
if (!found) values.push({id: 0, label: request.term + ' hinzufügen', value: request.term});
response(values);
```

It's about giving the option to create a new entry, if the input already matches an entry to prevent creating duplicate entries by the user as you can see in the last line. `request.term` is the value entered by the user and `values` is the array.

So for example, if I'm searching for "berlin" or "BERLIN" or "bERLiN" and the entry in my database is "Berlin", then it should still mark this item as found in the array.

Comment: Have you tried matching the strings with toLowerCase()? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolowercase.asp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option would be to force things upper- or lower-case beforehand:

```
var iterm = request.term.toLowerCase();
// ...
if (values[i].label.toLowerCase().split(',').indexOf(iterm) >= 0) {
```

Alternately you could turn `request.term` into a case-insensitive regular expression, but doing so involves escaping all of the characters in it that might be special in regular expressions, which is a pain. You'd have to be looking through a ***lot*** of values for the `toLowerCase` overhead to make me want to look at that complexity.

Comment: English isn't my mother-language, so I'm asking to be sure: Do you mean, if there are many values in my database containing special characters like `%$§`? Because there are only values allowed that contains space, normal letters and numbers.

Comment: @Vaia: I'm talking about special characters in `request.term`, not `values[i].label`. There are lots of characters with special meaning in regular expressions, such as `.`.

Comment: Yes, both `request.term` and `values[i].label` can't contain special characters. This will be validated server-side in `ajax.php` and the user gets an error message if there is something else than a letter, digit or whitespace. Is this a normal dot that you showed as an example?

Comment: @Vaia: Yes. It's commonly used in numbers. In many locales, it's the "decimal point" between the whole and fractional part of a number (`123.45` = one hundred twenty-three point 45). In some other locals, it's the "thousands separator" (`1.000.000` = one million). Note that parentheses (`()`) also have a special meaning in regular expressions, as do question marks (`?`), backslashes, and a number of other symbols.

Comment: Alright, I will keep that in mind. Thank you! My only current problem left is now that the JQuery UI autocomplete seems to stop functioning when I'm trying to enter multiple words (with a space). I can get results containing spaces, but the last `values.push` line doesn't respond anymore, but I guess I've to open a new question for that.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the values and term to lowercase:

```
if (values[i].label.toLowerCase().split(',').indexOf(request.term.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
   var found = values[i];
}
```